# How to get Unity's automatic injection to work on interface injected constructors?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

The Unity documentation states:

> *if a class that developers instantiate
>   using the Resolve method of the Unity
>   container has a constructor that
>   defines one or more dependencies on
>   other classes, **the Unity container
>   automatically creates the dependent
>   object instance** specified in
>   parameters of the constructor*

This is great, but most often I don't specify ***classes*** for injection but ***interfaces***, so as to keep things decoupled.

So how can I take advantage of Unity's automatic injection when I .Resolve<> **a class which specifies interface injection** instead of class injection?

i.e. in the following code, how can I make it work when I change my Customer constructor to "**public Customer(ILogger logger)**"?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace TestUnityInjection23
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer1 = new Customer(new BasicLogger());
            //Customer customer2 = new Customer(new AdvancedLogger()); //can't use this since Customer only accepts BasicLogger

            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<Customer>();
            container.RegisterType<ILogger, BasicLogger>();
            Customer customer3 = container.Resolve<Customer>();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public Customer(BasicLogger logger) //would like to have Customer depend on ILogger here so logger can be swapped out
        {
            logger.WriteToLog("creating the customer");
        }
    }

    public interface ILogger
    {
        void WriteToLog(string text);
    }

    public class BasicLogger : ILogger
    {

        public void WriteToLog(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }

    public class AdvancedLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void WriteToLog(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** {0} ***", text);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Unity, but every other DI framework I know does that and I'm sure Unity must do that too.

Have you tried changing the Customer constructor and seeing if it works? Cos it should.

Comment: yes it does work if I do that, problem was I had been trying "container.RegisterType<ILogger>()" which of course doesn't specify if BasicLogger or AdvancedLogger should be injected at runtime. I was wondering how the container was going to decide which to use, makes sense now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if too late but I think

using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
            {
                container.RegisterType();

```
            container
                .RegisterType<ILogger, BasicLogger>()
                .Configure<InjectedMembers>()
                .ConfigureInjectionFor<Customer>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(BasicLogger)));

            var customer3 = container.Resolve<Customer>();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();


public class Customer
        {
            public BasicLogger Logger { get; set; }
            public Customer(ILogger logger) 
            {
                logger.WriteToLog("creating the customer");
            }
        }
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use generic

```
public interface ILogger<T> where T: class
{

}

public class BasicLogger:ILogger<BasicLogger>
{

}

public class AdvanceLogger:ILogger<AdvanceLogger>
{

}
```